# Rsyslog forward using original source IP over TLS

Tags: ssl, syslog, rsyslog

I'm trying to forward all syslog messages over TLS from our enviroment to an external syslog server (*dest.syslog.example.com*) using rsyslog. Unfortunately the source IP is changed to that of the relay host (*fwd.syslog.example.com*). I would like it to send the original source IP instead of the IP of the relay host while adhering to the `RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format` format.

Current rsyslog configuration relevant for forwarding the syslog messages over TLS:

```
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.crt
# Run driver in TLS mode
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name

$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer dest.syslog.example.com
$LocalHostName fwd.syslog.example.com
# Forward logging
*.* @@(o)dest.syslog.example.com:6514;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

Would it be possible to modify the `fromhost-ip` to the original source IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is sufficient, but the built-in template `RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format` is defined as

```
"<%PRI%>1 %TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %APP-NAME% 
 %PROCID% %MSGID% %STRUCTURED-DATA% %msg%\n"
```

and you can replace `HOSTNAME` by `fromhost` or `fromhost-ip`:

```
template(name="myFormat" type="string"
   string="<%PRI%>1 %TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %fromhost% %APP-NAME% %PROCID% %MSGID% %STRUCTURED-DATA% %msg%\n")
*.* @@(o)dest.syslog.example.com:6514;myFormat
```